# How do I write urilify string python

Tags: python

### Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. You may assume that the string
has sufficient space at the end to hold the additional characters, and that you are given the "true" length of the string.

This is how I tried to solve, but I know I haven't addressed the question correctly where author asks us to assume the additional space at the end and the true length of the string. I am a beginner in programming trying to learn Algorithms and DS, quite a head bagging on this side.

```py
def replace(astring):

    alist= list(astring)

    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if alist[i] == ' ':
            alist[i]= '%20'
    return (''.join(alist))

print(replace("Mr John Smith "))
```

Comment: You know that the string type has a [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method, right?

Comment: What does "assume the additional space at the end and the true length of the string" mean? Is your function returning unexpected results? If so, what do you expect it to return instead?

Comment: @khelwood Yes , I am aware of replace. But my concern is weather second part of question from the CTCI is addressed with [def replace(astring): return astring.replace(' ','%20')].

Comment: The instructions don't make sense. A Python string is immutable, so having "sufficient space at the end to hold additional characters" is meaningless. And what does "true length" of the string mean? Were the instructions written for a different programming language?

Comment: @Khelwood, I am solving Cracking the Coding Interview, problem 1.3. Like I said I am beginner in Algo and DS.I don't understand the second part

Comment: The answer to the first part: "replace all spaces in a string with '%20'" is `astring.replace(' ','%20')`, and the rest of the instructions are meaningless if you're using Python.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you .That really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to learn algorithms, I think it will be beneficial to leave two hints to help you forward instead of the answer

1. `"Mr John Smith ".rstrip()` will strip any space at the end of a string. This means you will not have to worry about any logic for whitespace
2. Even though the solution works, you are using extra space by creating `alist`. Maybe try replacing things in the string itself? In Python a string can already by accessed as a string. For example `astring[:2]` is valid. Also `'hello world!'.replace(' ', 'test')` is your friend

Comment: @SamiraKarki that is correct. Since you are creating a new list, that explains why your solution is `O(n)`. If you change the string itself, no new list will be created and we will require no additional space (`O(1)`). 

Both solutions are `O(n)` in terms of time-complexity since we iterate over a list of length n to find all the blanks

Comment: Thank you. I think I understood .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```py
import urllib.parse

urllib.parse.quote("Mr John Smith ")
```